# dynamically create a div and combobox, and put combobox in the div using Dojo

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I want to create a div and `ComboBox` dynamically, then put the `ComboBox` in the div. Please see codes below. When i run the code, threw *Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…) "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'*.

What is the correct way to place the `ComboBox` in the div?

```js
var comboBox = new ComboBox({                           
    name: "state"
});
comboBox.set('style', {width: '100%', height: '35px', fontSize: '30px'});

var comboBoxDiv = domConstruct.create("div");
comboBoxDiv.id = "state";

domConstruct.place(comboBox, comboBoxDiv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `domConstruct` only handle `DOM` nodes, and you are trying to use it with an object, but, you can still use it, just need to pass the combobox `domNode`

```
domConstruct.place(comboBox.domNode, comboBoxDiv);
```

`domNode` is an attach point that all widgets have, it reference to the root template of the widget.

Also, I note that in your code, you are creating a div using `domConstruct`, but, you are not placing that div in the `DOM`. Something like this:

```
var comboBoxDiv = domConstruct.create("div");
domConstruct.place(comboBoxDiv, "someID");//or some node, attach point
```

Take a look to the [domConstruct documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html).

Another way to place a widget in the dom, is using the `placeAt` function.

```
var comboBoxDiv = domConstruct.create("div");

var myComboBox = new ComboBox({                           
    name: "state"
});

myComboBox.placeAt(comboBoxDiv);
```

Or, by passing a second argument to the constructor that can be a string( id of en element in the dome) or a node.

```
var comboBoxDiv = domConstruct.create("div");

var myComboBox = new ComboBox({                           
    name: "state"
}, comboBoxDiv);
```